# Dependency Injection In MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'am trying to implement "Dependency injection" for the first time and Iam a little unsure that I've made it right.

Here are my class and Interface:

```
public interface ICarHelper
{
    int CarInHouse();
}

public class Car : ICarHelper
{
    public int CarHouseID { set; get; }


    public int CarsInHouse { set; get; }
    public int CarSold    { set; get; }

    public int CarInHouse()
    {
        return this.CarsInHouse;
    }
}
```

Now in my HomeController, I do this:

```
    private readonly ICarHelper carobj = null;

    public HomeController(ICarHelper carService)
    {
        carobj = carService;
    }
```

Now Iam in a fuction Making an object and calling a funtion:

```
    public string DependencyInjection()
    {
     Car mycars = new Car {CarHouseID =120, CarsInHouse =200, CarSold =340};
     return Convert.ToString(carobj.CarInHouse());
    }
```

Something tells me that it is wrong to create the object in this way?!

Car mycars = new Car {CarHouseID =120, CarsInHouse =200, CarSold =340};

What to do...help ?

Comment: You do not create new Car object. You already have car object injected, it is "carobj" in your case. Object is created by dependency injection container, dependency injection make no sense if you create object with new. But this is not good example, dependency injection is usually used for service injection, car is business entity.

Comment: See the sample hier:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection

Comment: Raskolnikov , but .Net Framework dont allow me to say : carobj.CarHouseID=120;

Comment: @ImranKhan, yes it does, since CarHouseID setter is public. Anyway, I would like to suggest you to improve your basics, It seems you are confused, ICarHelper is not a helper it's an interface to a bussiness entity,  carService is not a service, it's a bussines entity, and you are trying to inject bussiness entities into controllers.

Comment: @Imran Khan: It is because you inject interface. CarHouseID is not member of ICarHelper  interface. You can call only CarInHouse() method, if you want something else you must include that to ICarHelper interface.

Comment: Does that mean I should use Dependency injection only for when I make the call to service classes and not ordinary classes? 

What is the definition of service classes?